# How to delete first pseudo after

Tags: html, css

I have three div and that are interconnected gray line.

Html code:

```
<div class="col-xs-3">
    <div class="middle-blue-bg">
        <!--Content-->
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.middle-blue-bg:after {
    background: #e2e2e2;
    height: 4px;
    width: 127px;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: 98px;
    left: -137px;
}
```

I need to remove the first line. How to do it?

Comment: I left before each block of the gray line. I need to first remove.

Comment: You need to expand your example a bit to make it more understandable. You are talking about three `<div>`'s, can you perhaps add the example to show all three?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `nth-child` property, as - `.middle-blue-bg:nth-child(n+2):after` to affect every element but first.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pwrx0cww/1/

Answer (score 1):

I think all You need is change your styles a little.
Here's example http://jsfiddle.net/59boz0wL/

I've changed `position: relative` and remove some other stuff to make it more clear.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

First child will do the trick, hust so you know there is also a last-child and nth-child

```css
div {border:2px solid red;display:inline-block;width:50px;margin:2px;}
div:first-child{border-left:none;}
div:last-child{border-right:none;}
div:nth-child(4n){border:4px solid blue;}
```

```html
<div>&nbsp;</div><div>&nbsp;</div><div>&nbsp;</div><div>&nbsp;</div><div>&nbsp;</div><div>&nbsp;</div><div>&nbsp;</div>
```